# Screen tearing on Loki [nvidia]

Tags: display, nvidia, graphics

I know there are a lot of posts asking for help on this, but anything had worked for me, so I ask for myself again...

I have a laptop with intel graphics and a nvidia gt 720m. I have problems of tearing on the screen. I selected in software & updates the latest (381.22) version of the nvidia drivers, I launched nvidia-settings but there is no "Sync to Vblank" option, and nothing seems like it. So, anyone has a possible solution?

Could I edit the xorg.conf and add the line that enables the "Sync to Vblank" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Nvidia GTX 765m, had screen tearing fixed. 2 things to do:

1) In Firefox open new tab, go to `about:config` and set `gfx.xrender.enabled` to `true`

2) Create a new folder `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and inside there create a file `20-intel.conf` which contents are:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

That's it.

In Nvidia Prime settings be sure you are using Intel Graphics as the default. After all these changes you *may* need to reboot.

Comment: The only solution on all of the Internet that worked. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I also don't have this option in my Xserver UI (GTX 1050)

Have you tried enabling SyncToVBlank via compiz?
[image]

Comment: How do I install that tool?

Comment: search for "compiz" in the app center and install "compizConfig". After its installed find OpenGL and enable it. then search for VSync setting

Comment: Sync to VBlank is checked but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can enable, in the advanced properties of your graphic driver, the force pipeline rendering and force full pipeline rendering.

Could you confirm us in which application do you have the tearing issue ?

Comment: I don't have that options in the advanced properties of nvidia-settings. The issue is in all applications, including the OS itself. It is very annoying in Chrome and other browsers, specially in full screen.

Answer (score -1):

This help my https://www.cmscritic.com/how-to-fix-nvidia-screen-tearing-in-xfce-mate-kde-lxde-and-others/..........................